# WSO2 Governance Registry for FuseSource

Tags: wso2, fuseesb, wso2-governance-registry

Would it be a good Idea to use WSO2 Governance Registry with Fuse ESB, would it be possible to leverage any of the registry features on doing so?

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 0):

The features of Governance Registry is leveraged to use with WSO2 ESB. But it does not mean that you can not integrate with any other third party ESB when it comes to resource handling, but would depend on you requirements.